# Image captions in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: images, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, photos

I want to add images with a caption to my long document in Microsoft Word. The standard way is usually to add a textfield below the image and group the two objects together.

However, for some reason it won't let me do that.

So that's why I want to ask:

1. Is there a more elegant solution?
2. What could be the reason of me being unable to group the objects together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always right click the image and choose `Insert Caption`, However I actually do something similar to you.

I personally insert a picture a box then just mess around with the text wrapping / position. Not elegant but it works.

Comment: Yes, I am now using the caption thing, too (didn't know it existed) in combination with a textfield around the picture and the caption, so that they are easy to move together. The only thing that still annoys me is the numbers that are added to the captions automatically with no option to remove them (have to do it by hand in the text).